# Exporting SQL to CSV does print out all the entries

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

I am trying to export my SQL data as a CSV file however when I do, in the CSV it does not print out the first entry only the second one

Here is the code:

```
                <?php  
                 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','grad_gown');
                if (!$connect){ 
                    die("Can not connect:". mysqli_error()); 
                }    
                $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','grad_gown'); 

                ////////////////////////////////////// 
                //////////////////////////////////////// 
                if (isset($_POST['back'])){   
                header("Location: http://localhost/login_grad_2.php");  
                exit; 
                }  
                //////////////////////////////////////  

                //Exporting mysql database to excel file
                $filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';   
                $fp = fopen($filename,"w");
                $sql = $db -> query( "SELECT * FROM `excel_info`") or die;
                $row_234 = $sql -> fetch_assoc(); 
                $seperator = ""; 
                $comma = ""; 

                //names/headers
                foreach($row_234 as $name => $value){  
                $seperator .= $comma.''.str_replace('','""',$name); 
                $comma = ",";    
                }
                $seperator .= "\n";   
                fputs($fp,$seperator);

                ///values display  
                while($row_234 = $sql -> fetch_assoc() ){  
                $seperator = ""; 
                $comma = ""; 
                foreach($row_234 as $name => $value){  
                $seperator .=        $comma.''.str_replace('','""',$value); 
                $comma = ",";    
                } 
                $seperator .= "\n";   
                fputs($fp,$seperator);
                } 

                fclose($fp);
                ?>
```

So is there problem with my code? Is there anyway that I can get the program to display all my entries from my SQL to the CSV file

Comment: You're using the first row that you fetch to render the heading line; but need to display the data that it contains as well

Comment: But why are you ignoring PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the first row value because you already fetched it for the name/headers but did not export the values.

A quick fix would be to replace you're `while` by a `do ... while` so that the first row values be exported before the second fetch

Comment: thank you, your suggestion with using the do while worked, appreciate your time and help